# Nested JSON file is the same source of data for the main view and the modal popup. How?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, json, bootstrap-modal

### Description of the application:

I am implementing a simple MVC application. It simply consists of a view that shows information which is delivered from a JSON file (no DB in my case).
I have developed the model, the controller and the view. The implementation is pretty classic like the following:

- Model:

The Model contains the representations of the classes based on the JSON data.

- Controller:

In the controller I read the JSON data using: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` (from NewtonSoft), then I give the output to the model, then I return the model to the view.

- View:

In the view, nothing particular, just displaying some data from the model to show it in a table.

### Problem

I would like to add a "details" action, for example: when the user clicks on one of the table elements in the table in the view page, a popup appears showing additional information about that element, coming from the SAME JSON file.

My JSON file is nested, it has at least 4 layers. the particular element that I want to show is in the 3rd layer.

I used modal bootstrap, to show a "details" popup/window upon div click, but my problem is how can I access the JSON file again from the modal?
Some solutions here and there propose going with the ID:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
```

That would have been easy to implement if I were using a DB but I do not know how to deal with getting information from a nested JSON to a modal view.
(The JSON is dynamic and a generic solution is needed, no way for accessing the JSON nodes with static values)

### Summary:

Having a dynamic JSON file as the only source of data for the MVC app, how can I display a modal popup/window upon clicking on an element in the main view (index), and show information about the element coming from the same JSON?

Comment: Just have the JSON file in you ASP.NET project and use AJAX to get the file from the web server. I.e., if it's in a folder called "data", you can use `fetch('/data/data.json').then(response => response.json()).then(data => /* do something with data */)` to get the data.

Comment: it is not that simple , not sure you got exactly what I need .
here I am stuck in an architectural decision that I cannot take.  I am looking for a solution to display specific JSON data for specific butons (variable number of buttons with different ID) ,  for example , Like you have a dynamic list of Users shown in a grid , and when you click on one of them you get the popup model that shows the information of that specific user  from the same JSON file that has been used .